# SQL y Java :La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados

Tags: java, sql, mvc

Esta es mi clase que se encuentra en un paquete, donde tengo un método para la conexion y otro método con el que ejecuto la consulta y recibe como parámetro el query:

```
    package org.COREBITS.prueba.bd;
public class ConexionSQL {

    public static Connection con = null;

    public static Connection conectar() {
        String baseDeDatos = "COREBITS_prueba";
        String usuario = "pruebaLogin";
        String password = "prueba123";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=" + baseDeDatos;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo establecer la conexion... revisar el Driver" + e.getMessage(), "Error de Conexion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
            System.out.println("Existosa Conexion a la Base de Datos");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + e.getMessage(), "Error de Conexion a la BD", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static ResultSet ejecutarConsulta(String query) {
        Connection conn = conectar();
        Statement declara;
        try {
            declara = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = declara.executeQuery(query);
            return rs;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + e.getMessage(), "Error de Conexion al Ejecutar la Query",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

y esta dos metodos donde tengo la query de sql para insertar los empleados y otro query para obtenerlos.

```
package org.COREBITS.prueba.bd;
    /**
     * Este método crea la consulta SQL que inserta un empleado en la tabla
     * empleado de la B.D.
     *
     * @param emp : El objeto que contiene los datos del empleado a insertar.
     * @return
     *
     */
    public static String insertarEmpleado(empleado emp) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO empleado (nombreEmpleado,claveEmpleado,idRol) "
                + "VALUES('" + emp.getNombreEmpleado() + "','"
                + emp.getClaveEmpleado() + "'," + emp.getRol() + ");";
        return query;
    }

public static String getConsultarEmpleado() {
    String consulta = "select emp.*, r.descripcionRol\n"
            + "FROM empleado emp\n"
            + " INNER JOIN Rol r ON emp.idEmpleado=r.idRol";
    return consulta;
}
```

y esta otra clase donde tengo otros métodos para ejecutar las consultas, en el paquete controlador , donde ejecuto la consulta:

```
package org.COREBITS.prueba.controller;
    /**
     * Inserta un Empleado en la Base de Datos.
     *
     * @param emp
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void insertarEmpleado(empleado emp) throws Exception {
        ConexionSQL conexion = new ConexionSQL();
        String query = null;

        //Primero abrimos una conexion con la BD:
        conexion.conectar();

        //Creamos la consulta SQL:
        query = CommandsEmpleado.insertarEmpleado(emp);

        //Ejecutamos la consulta
        conexion.ejecutarQuery(query);

        //Cerramos la conexion:
        conexion.desconectar();
    }

public String[][] consultarTodasLosEmpleados() throws Exception {
    //Creamos un objeto de conexion:
    ConexionSQL conexion = new ConexionSQL();

    //Declaramos el ResultSet:
    ResultSet rs = null;

    //Declaramos la matriz de datos:
    String[][] datos = null;

    //Declaramos una variable para
    //guardar el numero de renglones:
    int renglones = 0;

    int renglonActual = 0;

    //Establecemos la conexion con la BD:
    ConexionSQL.conectar();

    //Ejecutamos la consulta y guardamos el resultado en el ResultSet:
    Statement stmt = ConexionSQL.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(CommandsEmpleado.getConsultarEmpleado());

    //Intentamos movernos al ultimo registro:
    if (rs.last()) {
        renglones = rs.getRow(); //<-Devuelve el numero de registro
        datos = new String[renglones][rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];
        //datos = new String[renglones][5];
    }

    //Nos movemos al principio del ResultSet:
    rs.beforeFirst();

    //Iteramos sobre cada registro devuelto:
    while (rs.next()) {
        datos[renglonActual][0] = "" + rs.getInt("idEmpleado");
        datos[renglonActual][1] = "" + rs.getString("nombreEmpleado");
        datos[renglonActual][2] = "" + rs.getString("claveEmpleado");
        datos[renglonActual][3] = rs.getString("idRol");
        datos[renglonActual][4] = rs.getString("descripcionRol");
        renglonActual++;
    }

    //Cerramos el ResultSet:
    rs.close();

    //Cerramos la conexion:
    conexion.desconectar();

    //Devolvemos la matriz de datos:
    return datos;
}
```

el problema esta en que cuando hago la consulta para obtener los registros, solo me manda los tres primeros de la tabla que tengo en sql, cuando tengo más de 6
[image: solo me muestra 3 registros]
[image: tengo más de 6 registros]

y también cuando inserto un empleado me sale el siguiente error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Un par de cosas: a) en general, en internet las mayúsculas se consideran como "gritar" y de mal gusto, tenlo en cuenta para futuros posts y b) mirando tu código no veo nada que explique lo que se muestra; ayudaría si añades algo de log a tus código para ver cómo funciona. Por ejemplo, hacer `System.out.println` para cada valor que se recupera del `ResultSet`. En todo caso, no parece un problema del código que muestras.

Comment: Lo lamento y Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta, igual al hacer el resulset con System.out.println me devuelve solo los 3 primeros registros y no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema con la `insert` está claro. Usas el mismo método para `selects` que `inserts` y ahí radica el problema.
En tu código llamas a `conexion.ejecutarQuery(query);` con la `insert`, y en ese método se hace:

```
ResultSet rs = declara.executeQuery(query);
```

Esto es correcto para la select, pero no para la insert, ya que una insert (o una update o delete) no devuelve un ResultSet, y de ahí el `La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados.` Deberías hacer algo similar a

```
int elementosInsertados = declara.executeUpdate(query);
```

El método `executeUpdate(String sql)` devuelve el número de elementos afectados por la `sql` (`insert`, `update` o `delete`).

En cuanto al listado, ¿estás seguro de que la `query` es correcta? Estás cruzando las dos tablas en base a `idEmpleado=idRol`, y por eso no te salen los registros con `idEmpleado` superior a 3. Has debido copiar mal la consulta al pasarla a `java`.

Comment: ¿entonces como puedo hacer el método para realizar la inserción?, a lo que te eh entendido es que el `insert` esta bien y tendría que hacer otro método para ejecutar ya sean (`insert`,`update` o `delete`).  

y En cuanto al listado, eh echo la consulta de la siguiente forma en SQL:
    `SELECT emp.*,r.descripcionRol
FROM empleado emp
INNER JOIN rol r ON emp.idRol=r.idRol`
    
y si me devuelve todos los registros, pero java no y al hacer un `select * from empleados` si me regresa todo en Java

Comment: Lee la select de consulta que has puesto arriba, en Java, y compara con la que acabas de poner en el comentario.

Comment: Ya pude con los registros, estaba haciendo mal el JOINN
ahora lo eh hecho así:
 public static String getConsultarEmpleado() {
  String consulta = "select emp.*, r.descripcionRol\n"
    + "FROM empleado emp\n"
    + " INNER JOIN Rol r ON r.idRol=emp.idRol";
  return consulta;
 }

Comment: Para la insert, crea un método que sustituya a ejecutarQuery, y que llame al método executeUpdate que te indicado.

Comment: deja lo intento, una pregunta así rápida ¿como puedo identar el código en los comentarios?. No eh podido y no entiendo la guía.

Comment: Yo lo hago a mano, ni idea!

Comment: ¿como lo haces a mano? podrías mostrarme como.
ya quedo todo, ya pude resolverlo.

Comment: No hago nada especial, vamos. Sólo escribo.

Comment: ¿como se agradece? y ¿como se cierra la pregunta?, disculpa mi ignorancia, ya ah quedado resuelto. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada! Para eso está el sitio